# Parallelize while/for in OpenMP - files in directory

Tags: for-loop, parallel-processing, directory, openmp

I have a piece of code that searches a pattern in files within some directory. The point is how to parallelise this. My first version:

```
DIR * dptr = opendir(DIRNAME);
struct dirent *dir;
while(dir = readdir(dptr)) != NULL) {
    // searching in dir -> d_name;
}
```

So I transformed while to for:

```
#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp for
for(;(dir = readdir(dptr)) !=NULL;) {
    // searching
}
```

But now I have an error:

"Expected iteration declaration or initialization before ';' token. for(;(dir = readdir(dptr)) !=NULL;) "

Do you have any idea how to organise going over every file in the directory with the proper for loop?

Comment: Code like this is very likely I/O bound anyway, in which case you won't get any speedup even if you do parallelize it...

Comment: Even for large input files?

Comment: Especially for large input files! The bottleneck is likely moving data from the  files into memory, not processing the data. With large files you'll spend less time in the kernel opening/closing them, but still have to move all the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenMP `parallel for` directive splits iteration vector between threads. In order to do this, it takes loops in so-called `canonical` forms. I.e. `for(statement; expression; expression)` and you cannot skip a part of the loop. In addition, bound `expression` shall be one of forms: `less-expr (<), more-expr (>)` and their equal forms: `less-equal-expr (<=), more-equal (>=)`.

So, to fix your code, you need

1. Write initializer and increment in `for` loop
2. Rewrite bound expression (it currently uses `ne-expr (!=)`